# Generating multivariate heteroskedastic data

Tags: heteroscedasticity, vector-autoregression

I am trying to estimate a VAR model with heteroskedastic error terms.

$e_{it}$ is given by $η_{i,t} √h_{ii,t}$, where $η_{i,t}$ is iid, N(0,1).

[image]

I am trying to get $e_{it}$

Does anyone have any suggestions about how I might do this?